# LWC - Rename file before upload JS to Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, fileupload

I want to automatically change/update the name of a file as it's uploaded.

I'm accepting files as these formats only

```
  get acceptedFormats() {
    return ['.pdf', '.png','.jpg','.jpeg'];
  }
```

So for the instance, I will be accepting image files as random file names as the user uploads their image files. Then I want to put them as unique file names ex)image_0, image_1

I've been approaching apex code with JS as a new learner, so this is my understanding of updating file names.

```
const newName = new Date().getTime() + event.target.files[0].name;  
fd.append('file[]', event.target.files[0], newName);
```

I'm using the time stamps for the unique file name.
Hope someone could help me implement this in the apex code, and if you have a better recommendation, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code, hope it helps and answers your requirement

fileupload.html

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="File Upload Demo LWC" icon-name="custom:custom14">
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <lightning-input type="file" 
        accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv, .png, .doc, .docx, .pdf"
        label="Attachment" onchange={openfileUpload}></lightning-input>
    </div>
    <template if:true={fileData}>
        <p>{fileData.filename}</p>
    </template>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="submit" title="Submit" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
</lightning-card>
```

we are fetching the record id using **@api**, and this id is required to send the file to the apex.As soon as the file upload **onchange**,

we call **openfileUpload** handler that receives an event from which we extract the details of the file like name, size, etc.
Inside **openfileUpload** method, we use browser **FileReader** API to generate the data stream.

On click of the submit button, **handleClick** method gets called, and it calls the apex method **uploadFile**.

Once the file upload is completed, it will trigger the toast method that shows the screen's success messag
fileupload.js

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import uploadFile from '@salesforce/apex/FileUploaderClass.uploadFile'
export default class FileUploaderCompLwc extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
fileData
 openfileUpload(event) {
 const file = event.target.files[0]
  var reader = new FileReader()
reader.onload = () => {
 var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1]
this.fileData = {
 'filename': file.name,
 'base64': base64,
 'recordId': this.recordId
 }
        console.log(this.fileData)
 }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}
   handleClick(){
    const {base64, filename, recordId} = this.fileData
    uploadFile({ base64, filename, recordId }).then(result=>{
        this.fileData = null
        let title = `${filename} uploaded successfully!!`
        this.toast(title)
    })
}

toast(title){
    const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
        title, 
        variant:"success"
    })
    this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent)
}
}
```

Apex controller

```
public with sharing class FileUploaderClass {
  /*
* @method uploadFile() 
* @desc Creates a content version from a given file's base64 and name
* @param {String} base64 - base64 string that represents the file
* @param {String} filename - full file name with extension, i.e. 'products.csv'
* @param {String} recordId - Id of the record you want to attach this file to
* @return {ContentVersion} - returns the created ContentDocumentLink Id if the
*   upload was successful, otherwise returns null
*/
   @AuraEnabled
  public static String uploadFile(String base64, String filename, String recordId) {
        ContentVersion cv = createContentVersion(base64, filename);
        ContentDocumentLink cdl = createContentLink(cv.Id, recordId);
        if (cv == null || cdl == null) { return null; }
         return cdl.Id;}
/*


  * @method createContentVersion() [private]
  * @desc Creates a content version from a given file's base64 and name
  * @param {String} base64 - base64 string that represents the file
  * @param {String} filename - full file name with extension, i.e. 'products.csv'
  * @return {ContentVersion} - returns the newly created ContentVersion, or null
  *   if there was an error inserting the record
*/
  private static ContentVersion createContentVersion(String base64, String filename) {
    ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
    cv.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64);
    cv.Title = filename;
    cv.PathOnClient = filename;
       try {
          insert cv;
          return cv;
          } catch(DMLException e) {
            System.debug(e);
     return null;
    }}
 /*


* @method createContentLink() [private]
* @desc Creates a content link for a given ContentVersion and record
* @param {String} contentVersionId - Id of the ContentVersion of the file
* @param {String} recordId - Id of the record you want to attach this file to
* @return {ContentDocumentLink} - returns the newly created ContentDocumentLink, or null if there was an error inserting the record
*/
private static ContentDocumentLink createContentLink(String contentVersionId, String recordId) {
          if (contentVersionId == null || recordId == null) { return null; }
      ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
      cdl.ContentDocumentId = [
      SELECT ContentDocumentId 
      FROM ContentVersion 
      WHERE Id =: contentVersionId
      ].ContentDocumentId;
    cdl.LinkedEntityId = recordId;
    // ShareType is either 'V', 'C', or 'I'
    // V = Viewer, C = Collaborator, I = Inferred
     cdl.ShareType = 'V';
     try {
     insert cdl;
     return cdl;
     } catch(DMLException e) {
  System.debug(e);
  return null;
}}}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks @paven I'm currently reviewing this. I'm very new to Apex controller. Do you know where the Apex controller supposed to be stored?